# What table links a simple product to a configurable product

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product

I have imported some products and for some items, I can see all the children linked in the associated tab but for some others, I can only see one or 2 of the options.

If I do

```
select * from catalog_product_super_link where parent_id = {my parent id}
```

Then it shows ALL the correct product ids linked. Is there another table which links the two?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The table `catalog_product_super_link` but the other tables that start with `catalog_product_super_` are involved in the relation.

1. `catalog_product_super_attribute` - holds the configurable
   attributes
2. `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` - holds the store view
   labels for the configurable attributes - this is not that important
3. `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` - holds the price
   differences for the simple variations

There is also the table `catalog_product_relation` that seam to remember the configurable products relations.
**[EDIT]**
After checking I confirm that the configurable products relations are remembered in 2 tables. This seams redundant but I'm sure there is a reason.
In the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable::saveProducts()` there is this that inserts the data in `catalog_product_super_link` :

```
 $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertMultiple($this->getMainTable(), $data);
```

And after that there is this that saves the data in `catalog_product_relation`:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_relation')
    ->processRelations($mainProductId, $productIds);
```

Comment: Ok, `catalog_product_relation` has both items. `catalog_product_super_attribute` has the correct `attribute_id` associated. Anywhere else that could be breaking the link?

Comment: This answers the question. My issue was the `has_options` and `required_options` being set to `1` against the children so they didn't show.

Comment: p.s Many thanks Marius, useful information.

Comment: Table `catalog_product_relation` is used by indexers. Simple associated attributes values are stored in table `catalog_product_index_eav` too. If the relations are missing in the first table than there won't be values in the second table for associated products. The result is no options to select for associated products in filter navigation (e.g. values of attributes like: color, size, ..).