# what is difference between catalog_product_super_link and catalog_product_relation table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, configurable-product, product-relations

I have created a configurable product with 2 simple products and child products and parent product relations are added in two different tables(`catalog_product_super_link` and `catalog_product_relation table` ).Anybody can get clear what uses of two tables ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What table links a simple product to a configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/what-table-links-a-simple-product-to-a-configurable-product)

Comment: Prince Patel, please  read the question,  before  put a comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### `catalog_product_super_link` table save

only Configurable  products and its child products relationShip.

### Where `catalog_product_relation` save

- configurable  products and its child products relationship
- group products and its child products relationship
- bundle products and its child products relationship.